# Endeca DefaultFileStoreFactory component

Tags: atg, endeca

Recently, I am facing some issues with the Endeca `DefaultFileStoreFactory` component.
Site is not coming up and when checked for this component, the initialized property is becoming false automatically.
We are giving a temporary solution to bring up the site.
Could you please assist why this behavior is happening.

Below are the logs seen at the time of server start up.

```
**** Error      Tue Jan 02 15:22:34 -03:00 2018 1514917354914   /       Unable to resolve component /atg/endeca/assembler/cartridge/manager/DefaultFileStoreFactory     java.lang.StackOverflowError
**** Error      Tue Jan 02 15:22:34 -03:00 2018 1514917354914   /               at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$SubMapIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1700)
**** Error      Tue Jan 02 15:22:34 -03:00 2018 1514917354914   /               at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$SubMapEntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1747)
**** Error      Tue Jan 02 15:22:34 -03:00 2018 1514917354914   /               at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$SubMapEntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1741)
```

Comment: Can you add more of the stack trace? The first 4 lines isn't enough.

Comment: Please check, maybe you will find [this](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2129110.1&_adf.ctrl-state=12d7pax6tg_4&_afrLoop=379149074002655) helpful: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2129110.1&_adf.ctrl-state=12d7pax6tg_4&_afrLoop=379149074002655

Comment: According to the ticket: Cause

The default stack size of 256k was exceeded, causing the error seen in the application server logging.
Solution

The size of the Java stack must be increased. The default Java stack size is configured using the Xss argument in JAVA_ARGS (or JAVA_OPTS on JBoss). In many scenarios, this value defaults to 256k. Doubling this value resolved this issue ( -Xss512k ). The optimal value will depend on the customer's specific application needs.

Comment: @PanagiotisStoupos Perhaps you can add your last comment as an answer. Looks like it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @radimpe . I will try the above suggestion

Answer (score 2):

According to [this oracle support ticket](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=466348008082366&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2129110.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=1u6fpu9i1_4):

The default stack size of 256k was exceeded, causing the error seen in the application server logging. 
In order to resolve this, the size of the Java stack must be increased. The default Java stack size is configured using the Xss argument in JAVA_ARGS (or JAVA_OPTS on JBoss). In many scenarios, this value defaults to 256k. Doubling this value resolved this issue ( -Xss512k ). The optimal value will depend on the customer's specific application needs.

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis stoupos.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation. I agree that increasing **-Xss param  is standard way** of solving the issue (reason is that DefaultStoreFactory build "tree" based on Experience Manager content with **recursive algorithm**). But I would suggest also to review structure of Experience Manager in order to **decrease unused and useless data**, in other case - you will need to keep this "tree" in memory (heap) and it can raise out of memory issue (it's actually was my case :) )

Comment: Child_ron, Could you please tell what kind of data you are referring here?

Comment: Could you please tell me what kind of data you are referring to.  Is it some thing like Experience Manager workspaces?